# use keyboard in org calendar

Tags: org-mode, advice

I want to use keyboard when selecting a date in calendar
(while setting deadline or schedule in org mode).

The cursor is set to nil and it's not visible where the cursor is.

I've tracked down the code

```
(org-eval-in-calendar '(setq cursor-type nil) t)
```

in the org.el file.
Similar question has been asked (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53717/12031)

and some history about it. (https://list.orgmode.org/87d36uip6p.fsf@gnu.org/)

How should I go about changing the behavior of this code?

I tried `:around` and `:after` . with error (if: Wrong type argument: stringp, (25816 61424))
I guess something wrong with my code

```
(defun my-org-read-date (orig-fn &rest args)
  (progn
    ;; (apply orig-fn args)

    (apply 'org-read-date args)
    (org-eval-in-calendar '(setq cursor-type t) t)
    )
  )

(advice-remove 'org-read-date  #'my-org-read-date)
(advice-add 'org-read-date :around #'my-org-read-date)



(defun my-cursor ()
  (org-eval-in-calendar '(setq cursor-type 'bar) t)
  )

(defun my-cursor2 ()
  (setq cursor-type 'bar)
  )


(add-hook 'calendar-mode-hook
          (define-key calendar-mode-map (kbd "!") 'my-cursor2)
          )
```

Comment: How about using an `advice-add` / `:after` with `org-read-date` that takes the calendar buffer and sets the cursor-type to make it visible again; e.g., `(with-current-buffer "*Calendar*" ...)`?  Such an approach would perhaps be preferred to redefining a large function such as `org-read-date` ...

Comment: @lawlist thanks for the suggestion, after I asked the question, I've tried few things, (I edited the OP), and it's not working yet..

Comment: @lawlist after seeing https://scripter.co/emacs-lisp-advice-combinators/, I think advice-add won't work, because org-read-date doesn't return until I select a date. and I need see the cursor before I select a date..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the master branch of Emacs 29 as of 08/12/2023, the behavior that needs to be changed is caused by line 13728 of `org.el`, within the function `org-read-date` -- i.e., `(org-eval-in-calendar '(setq cursor-type nil) t)`

https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org.el#L13728

One approach is to `advice` the function `org-eval-in-calendar` to look for the code at issue, and then substitute the argument at issue with a new argument, and then apply the function using said new argument:

```lisp
(defun my-func (orig-fun &rest args)
  (when (equal (car args) '(setq cursor-type nil))
    (setcar args '(setq cursor-type 'bar)))
  (apply orig-fun args))

(advice-add 'org-eval-in-calendar :around #'my-func)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought of setting the function (cursor-type) nil and using :before in order to nullify the effect of the line. well. TY!